# How to implemenet Password Resets

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an existing application that i want to implement password resets after 30 days.
But i dont want the user to use the same password as the last 5 times.

How do i go about doing this or is there any links i can follow.

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: You want your users to come up with a new unique password once a month? Are you serious?!

Comment: Getting users to change their password too often, increases the likelihood that they will record their password somewhere...

Comment: If you have any control over this process then I'd strongly recommend that you don't go with password resets every 30 days. It's counter-productive.

Comment: you're going to make them game your password system. They'll get workarounds like their regular pass with the month in front ("RonaldoApril" or something like that), changing pass six times so they get the same, and so on. New pass every month is taxing - imagine if you kept a few different passwords (I use ~5) and you had to change them every month... ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save a history of the last 5 passwords to prevent the user from reusing them
and save the last password change date.
once user perform login check if 30 days are over and if so redirect him to a page to reset his password.

Comment: That's ok...i got that..
But how can i implement it...
Can you plz specify?

Comment: i would add that you should store **hashes** of passwords not passwords. but idea is right.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small table having 5 columns so that you can store the last 5 passwords used. Each column will then contain the hash of the password, not the password itself.